# cannot install blackberry webworks plugin for eclipse helios

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I get following error while installing blackberry webworks plugin in eclipse helios:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>
> **Software being installed**: BlackBerry WebWorks SDK 2.0.0.201103231828-18 (net.rim.browser.tools.wcpc.feature.feature.group 2.0.0.201103231828-18)
>
> **Missing requirement**: BlackBerry Web Plug-in 2.5.1.201010291444-2 (net.rim.browser.tools.debug 2.5.1.201010291444-2) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ecore2xml [2.5.0,2.6.0)' but it could not be found
>
> **Cannot satisfy dependency**:
>
> **From**: BlackBerry WebWorks SDK Plug-in 2.0.0.201103231828-18 (net.rim.browser.tools.wcpc 2.0.0.201103231828-18)
>
> **To**: bundle net.rim.browser.tools.debug 0.0.0
>
> **Cannot satisfy dependency**:
>
> **From**: BlackBerry WebWorks SDK 2.0.0.201103231828-18 (net.rim.browser.tools.wcpc.feature.feature.group 2.0.0.201103231828-18)
>
> **To**: net.rim.browser.tools.wcpc [2.0.0.201103231828-18]

Answer (score 1):

The BlackBerry plugin for Eclipse is no longer supported (was end-of-lifed last year). Developers are encouraged to continue to use their favorite IDE (including Eclipse) for editing files along with the BlackBerry WebWorks SDK (for packaging) and the Ripple Mobile emulator (for previewing & testing) :

https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/download/

Lastly, there is an Ant build script published that can help make things much easier:

https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-WebWorks-Community-Samples/tree/master/Ant-Build-Script